# Laravel search feature without using collective for forms

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use a basic html form without using Laravel collective.

I have this code here.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{{route('patients.index')}}" method="get">

      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

And then in the PatientsController index function

```
public function index()
    {
       $search = \Request::get('search'); 

    $patients = Patient::where('lname','like', '%'.$search.'%');

    return view('/searchResults')->with('patients', $patients);
    }
```

When i return the view at the end of the function, it just loads a blank page. when i do $patients = Patient::all(), it yields my full database so i know that at least part of the query is right. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `searchResults` without `/`

```
 public function index()
 {
        $search = \Request::get('search');    
        $patients = Patient::where('lname','like', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        return view('searchResults', ['patients'=>$patients]);
 }
```

You blade template:

```
resources/views/searchResults.blade.php
```

Comment: no luck on this solution mate. still loads a blank page

Comment: @maximus1127 you use `->get()`?